# jQuery: Loading multiple images but just one oncomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to get just one complete call from an array of images using the load() function?

Example:

```
$(img_nodes).load(function()
{
    _this.scaleImages();
});
```

`img_nodes` contains two images `(<img>, array)`. This way causes two call to the function `_this.scaleImages();`

How can I set this up to get just one complete after ALL images are loaded from the array?

EDIT:

`img_node` content:

> var items_node    = $('root_node).find('.items');
>
> var img_nodes     = items_node.find('img');

Thank you!

Comment: Show us `img_nodes` content

Comment: you can use waitForImages jQuery plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a counter to the number of images. Each callback can decrement it, and when it reaches 0 you know that all the images have been loaded.

```
var counter = $(img_nodes).length;
$(img_nodes).load(function() {
    if (--counter == 0) {
        _this.scaleImages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many imgs you have,

```
var nbImgs = $(img_nodes).length;
var nbImgsLoaded = 0;
```

then on each load you increment nbImgsLoaded, and then you compare to nbImgs, if they're equal, means all your images loaded, then you can call whatever function you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$.each($('root_node).find('.items'),function(){
    $(this).scaleImages();
});
```